# Installing GIS tools in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download GIStools in R. I did this through the Packages menu > Install Packages. I then selected GIStools and it appears to have installed it as I get the following message:

*> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
trying URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/GISTools_0.7-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3460038 bytes (3.3 MB)
downloaded 3.3 MB
package ‘GISTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked*

*The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\MachineX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCCEk3L\downloaded_packages*

I didn't select a mirror site from which to d/l the package (was it supposed to prompt me?) When I call the library using library(GIStools) I get the following error:

*Error in library(GIStools) : there is no package called ‘GIStools’*

I'm not sure what I have done wrong - can anyone help? I am using R version 3.2.3. I am totally new to R, so apologies if this seems like a silly question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the console type `install.packages('GIStools')` make sure you are running rstudio as admin when doing this. This should install just fine make sure you don't have the rstudio screen maximized as the mirror prompt could be hidden.

Comment: Thanks Seekheart, this worked. I'm assuming that it didn't work the first time because I used a lower case 't'? Bit of a school-boy error there!

Comment: @JassiL glad I could help, if you could please close your question now by selecting my answer :)

Comment: @JassiL consider deleting this question if its just a matter of typo.